# PHP Google Docs API - Formating text error

Tags: php, google-docs-api

I'm trying to format a text from a GOOGLE DOC document using GOOGLE DOCS API.

Here is my code....

```
    $style = new Google_Service_Docs_TextStyle();
    $style->setBold(true);

    $range = new Google_Service_Docs_Range();
    $range->setStartIndex(1);
    $range->setEndIndex(4);

    $request = new Google_Service_Docs_UpdateTextStyleRequest();
    $request->setTextStyle($style);
    $request->setRange($range);
    $request->setFields('bold');

    $batchUpdateRequest = new Google_Service_Docs_BatchUpdateDocumentRequest();
    $batchUpdateRequest->setRequests($request);

    $this->docService->documents->batchUpdate($iddoc, $batchUpdateRequest);
```

when the code runs I get the error message:

> "error": {
> "code": 400,
> "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "fields" at 'requests': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "textStyle" at 'requests': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "range" at 'requests': Cannot find field.",
> "errors": [
> {
> "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "fields" at 'requests': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "textStyle" at 'requests': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "range" at 'requests': Cannot find field.",
> "reason": "invalid"
> }
> ],
> "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
> }

I don't understand what's happening: each of the fields referenced in the error message (fields, textStyle, range) have been correctly defined using the corresponded setter.

===== UPDATE ====

I tried another version (more simple) and I got the same error message...

```
    $request = [];
    $request[] = new Google_Service_Docs_UpdateTextStyleRequest(
        [
            "updateTextStyle" => [
                "fields" => "bold",
                "range" => [
                    "startIndex" => 1,
                    "endIndex" => 4,
                ],
                "textStyle" => [
                    "bold" => true
                ]
            ],
        ]
    );


    $batchUpdateRequest = new Google_Service_Docs_BatchUpdateDocumentRequest(array(
        'requests' => $request
    ));

    $this->docService->documents->batchUpdate($iddoc, $batchUpdateRequest);
```

Comment: I don't read the error message that those properties wouldn't be defined in the request and that is the problem. The opposite is the case: The input has these properties, and the API sees them, but it has not clue what to do with them and therefore complaints. Feel lucky the API is that talkative for the errors.

Comment: And please add a reference to the API documentation of the components you use, otherwise this question is missing the technical context which is not that helpful for others (and trouble-shooting).

Comment: See if the request works for you with the [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate?apix_params=%7B%22documentId%22%3A%22123%22%2C%22resource%22%3A%7B%22requests%22%3A%5B%7B%22updateTextStyle%22%3A%7B%22fields%22%3A%22bold%22%2C%22range%22%3A%7B%22startIndex%22%3A1%2C%22endIndex%22%3A4%7D%2C%22textStyle%22%3A%7B%22bold%22%3Atrue%7D%7D%7D%5D%7D%7D) to exclude language specific errors.

Comment: Thank you, ziganotschka,  for the sugestion. I had already done that and using the Api explorer everything worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is a problem with the Google_Service_Docs_BatchUpdateDocumentRequest class.
I managed to overcome this problem by making HTTP requests directly with Guzzle which is obtained using the authorize method from the Google client.

I leave the code in hope of being useful to anyone who comes across the same problem. IMPORTANT: I'm using a GOOGLE ACCOUNT SERVICE!

I apologize for my english

```
class Docs
{
   private $client;

   public function __construct()
   {

       $this->client = new Google_Client();
       $this->client->setApplicationName('Google Docs API');
       $this->client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ . '/atas-gdocs-cs2.json');
       $this->client->setAccessType('offline');
       $this->client->setSubject('impersonating a user'); // insert user enterprise email
       $this->client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents']);

  }

  public function format_text($iddoc)
  {
      $httpClient = $this->client->authorize();
      $url = "https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents/$iddoc:batchUpdate";

      $payload2 = [
         'requests' => [
            'updateTextStyle' => [
               'fields' => 'bold',
               'range' => [
                  'startIndex' => 1,
                  'endIndex' => 4,
               ],
               'textStyle' => [
                  'bold' => true
               ]
            ],
          ]
       ];

     $resposta = $httpClient->request('POST', $url, ['json' => $payload2]);
     echo $resposta->getBody();
   }
}
```